# How to get a list of all managed types from a persistence unit

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Input: 2 Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Table2")
public class Table2 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
 <class>data.Table1</class>
 <class>data.Table2</class>
```

I would like to get a list of all manged types from the persistence unit.

Output:

```
puplic List<List<Object> GetAllObjects();
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110202/how-can-i-get-all-entity-classes-from-a-persistence-unit) that I can solve my problem using `metamodel`

First of all metamodel.getEntities() returns all entities classes, which have @Entity annotation. And it doesn't know anything about persistence.xml.

After I got Set How can I get all objects from DB foreach EntityType?

Comment: Please provide more information WRT the entities involved and the expected and actual results. It is not clear what is being asked.

Comment: I refactor my question

Comment: I get it now. Since you have found an answer already, you can either mark the question as duplicate, remove it, or add an own answer and accept it.

Comment: Refactor my question v2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the `EntityManager` as `em` and the current entity class (while iterating over the set of all entity classes) as `entityClass` do:

```
// for each entity class {
    List<?> results = findAll(em, entityClass);
    doSomethingWithResults(results, entityClass);
// }
```

And add the following utility methods:

```
private <T> List<T> findAll(EntityManager em, Class<T> entityClass) {
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = makeAllCriteriaQuery(em, entityClass);
    TypedQuery<T> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<T> ret = tq.getResultList();
    return ret;
}
private <T> CriteriaQuery<T> makeAllCriteriaQuery(EntityManager em, Class<T> entityClass) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> q = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> root = q.from(entityClass);
    q.select(root);
    return q;
}
```

The drawback is that your method `doSomethingWithResults()` will receive a list of objects - it doesn't know the correct type. You can always enrich this example by adding e.g. an interface that will receive correctly typed lists, but this is the principle.